# Android: How to change/remove button stroke when holding/clicking button

Tags: android, button

So on the emulator, this menu icon looks like (when not pressed): [image: Button not pressed]

and when i press/hold it, it gets a bit of stroke/outline around it like this: [image: Button pressed]

However when I put the app on my (kitkat api) phone, the entire square around the circular icon gets highlighted, even on a simple click (not even holding). How can I remove/change that, preferably without adding a bunch of xml files.

I've spent quite some time searching for exactly what I mean here but most questions/answers were about changing color on click. Sorry if it has been answered before and thank you to everyone who tries to help.

Edit: just to further explain a bit, the icon is in a menu.xml, and the icons are called simply by android:icon="@drawable..." inside an item in menu.
This is what it looks like and I do not want the lighter colored background square: [pressed button on kitkat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOz4p.jpg)

Comment: Could you show us the code you use for your selector? Or do you use only images?

Comment: I just got a menu.xml and in there items with android:icon="@drawable/.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a selector from wich you can configure the button behaviour in button .xml file :
  ***/res/drawable/button.xml***

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unsel" />
</selector>
```

Don't use `<button>` use `<RelativeLayout>` instead

Comment: I've tried this but the light colored square remains. I've included a picture on the original post now. Thanks for the help. The square even appears if I just quickly click the button. To further explain, I tried just setting the menu item icon as a selector with all 3 drawables being the basic circular icon.

Comment: I think you have some changement in style.xml

Comment: I have a styles.xml file but that only has the theme colors defined. Is there anyway to just remove this "animation" when a button is pressed?

Comment: Its not an animation it't the behaviour when button is focused or pressed

Comment: You were right, I was just implementing it wrong. Thanks!